# change state checbox's checked after remove item list view

Tags: android, android-listview

custom list view with custom checkbox,

Example : i have 4 data and all checkbox checked, i write command to remove item using OnCheckedListener, so when i click checbox the second item, the second item dissapear. the thrid item going up but the checkbox on the third item become checked = false as in the screen (when i debug it, the value still checked=true)

if i remove the third item then the 4th checkbox will be uncheck.

how to resolve this problem?
thanks in advance, sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

In the `onClick()` or `onCheckedChanged()` method, whichever you are using, programmatically check which ones are checked, and toggle them.

Initialize as many `CheckBox` as you want, and then do this for all :

```
        if(chkbox1.isChecked()){
            chk1.toggle();
        }

        if(chkbox2.isChecked()){
            chk2.toggle();
        }
```